# Cropped 3D CSS elements in Chrome or no 3D at all in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

In my card game project, CSS elements (cards) from the map are being cropped in Chrome if the following CSS is added:

```
.state { transform-style: preserve-3d; }
```

But without this CSS, the 3D parallax from the menus don't work at all in Firefox.

Since the issue is not easily reproduced, I'll provide minimal explanation of the code, relevant CSS and the HTML structure.

Full code can be found on Github https://github.com/rafaelcastrocouto/foda and the whole thing is online here https://foda-app.herokuapp.com/

I know this is the result of different implementations in the browsers, I'm not looking for an in depth explanation, but only for a way to make it work in Firefox and Chrome.

```js
/* on 'body' mousemove change '.states' perspective-origin */
/* on '.card.skill' mousemove toggle '.map .card' className 'highlight' */
```

```css
body, html {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 485px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #22272c;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at center top,#6e7a66 0,#343b43 30%,#22272c 60%,#22272c 100%),#22272c;
  background-size: 100% 20%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 -50px 100px rgba(0,0,0,.7) inset;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.container, .states {
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
  color: #fff;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-color: #859890;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  will-change: transform;
}
.container, .container:after, .state, .states {
  width: 970px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
}
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.states {
  animation: persp 20s infinite;
}

.state, .states {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.states {
  transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
  perspective: 600px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  image-rendering: auto;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
  will-change: perspective-origin;
}
.table .camera {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  width: 718px;
  height: 450px;
  perspective: 800px;
  perspective-origin: 57% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.table .map {
  z-index: 0;
  transform: translate(-49.7%,-50.6%) rotateX(32deg) scale3d(.21,.21,.21);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: all 2s;
}
.map .spot {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 6px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all .3s,filter 2s,-webkit-filter 2s;
}
.map .row {
  height: 312px;
}
.states .table .map .card {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,2px);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card.trees, .card.trees .portrait {
  background-color: #5ba22f;
}
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  transition: all .3s;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #4d4843;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: #898;
  will-change: transform;
}
.menu .background {
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(1.3);
  background-size: 970px 405px;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.menu.paralax {
  height: 600px;
  width: 970px;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu .front {
  transform: scale(.25) translate3d(-1070px,720px,140px);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="states">
        <div class="state menu">
          <div class="parallax">
            <div class="background"></div>
            <div class="ground">
              <div class="icon single"></div>
              <div class="icon online"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="front"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="state table">
          <div class="decks player">
            <div class="hand">
              <div class="card skill"></div>
              <div class="card skill"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="camera">
            <div class="map">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="spot">
                  <div class="card hero"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="spot">
                  <div class="card trees"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I couldn't see a reason why this was downvoted, it seemed like a nicely formulated question as well as being a question it might be reasonable to ask, so I voted it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by creating separated containers with their own `perspective` for each parallax scene, instead of having them all under the `states` div with a single control.

So basically instead of:

```
 /* on 'body' mousemove change '.states' perspective-origin */
```

Now I'm doing:

```
 /* on 'body' mousemove change '.current.state .parallax' perspective-origin */
```

And it works for Chrome and Firefox, without cropping. Of course, the `.state { transform-style: preserve-3d; }` was not needed at all.